# Use regular buttons as radio buttons, with the possibility to unselect any of them (toggle jQuery)

Tags: jquery, radio-button

Let's say I have two steps of my form that I want my visitors to fill in, like the code below.

Only one button for each step is allowed to have the class "button-chosen". If I press another button with the class "button-choose", the previously selected button should toggle back to the class "button-choose" and the newly clicked button should toggle to the class "button-chosen".

If I click on a button that already has the class "button-chosen" it should toggle back to "button-choose". All this using jQuery.

```
<div id="step-one">
   <div class="box">
        Information
        <input type="button" class="button-choose" />
   </div>
   <div class="box">
        Information
        <input type="button" class="button-chosen" /> <!-- A button that the visitor has clicked -->
   </div>
   <div class="box">
        Information
        <input type="button" class="button-choose" />
   </div>
</div>
<div id="step-two">
   <div class="box">
        Information
        <input type="button" class="button-choose" />
   </div>
   <div class="box">
        Information
        <input type="button" class="button-chosen" /> <!-- A button that the visitor has clicked -->
   </div>
   <div class="box">
        Information
        <input type="button" class="button-choose" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function() {
    var p = $(this).parent().parent();
    $("input[type='button']", p).not($(this)).removeClass("button-chosen").addClass("button-choose");
    $(this).toggleClass("button-chosen button-choose");
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ajBtg/1/

Comment: Is there a way to make this work if I have more than one button in each .box-container? There are two buttons where only the one with the class "button-choose" or "button-chosen" should be affected of the click function. Sorry for not mentioning this earlier and thanks for the great reply!

http://jsfiddle.net/ajBtg/4/

Comment: You would have to target those two specific classes and not all the buttons, something like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ajBtg/6/).....

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```js
$("input[type='button']").click(
     function(){
         if($(this).hasClass("button-choose"))
             $(this).removeClass("button-choose").addClass("button-chosen");
         else
             $(this).removeClass("button-chosen").addClass("button-choose");
     }
);
```

Comment: This seem to allow more than one button with the class "button-chosen".